# Inserting options in drop down list in a WordPress plugin

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm currently modifying the registration page in a plugin where I want to add a drop down list which will insert the names of the states.

I'm importing the states name from database according to its ID in PHP.
Here is the code:

```
$localVar = '';
$query=$wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT * FROM wp_state
    ");

if (isset($_POST['user_state']))
    $localVar = $_POST['user_state'];
    $registerFilterArray2['name20'] = '
        <p class="user_state'.$errorVar.'">
        <label for="user_state">'. __('State', 'profilebuilder') .$errorMark.'</label>
        <select name="state">
        <option value="default">Choose Your State</option>';
    $count=0;

    foreach($query as $res)
    {
        '<option value="'.$query[$count]->state_id.'">"'.$query[$count]->state_name.'"</option>';
        $count++;                                    
    } 

    '   </select>;

        <input class="text-input" name="user_state" type="text" id="user_state" value="'.trim($localVar).'" />
        </p><!-- .user_state -->';

    $registerFilterArray2['name20'] = apply_filters(
        'wppb_register_content_name20', 
        $registerFilterArray2['name20'], 
        trim($localVar), 
        $errorVar, 
        $errorMark
    );
```

Is there any pre-defined function in WordPress to add drop down list to a registration page ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, WordPress has the following `wp_dropdown_*` functions.

[image: wordpress dropdown functions]

- `wp_dropdown_roles` (undocumented)
- [`wp_dropdown_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories)
- [`wp_dropdown_pages`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages)
- [`wp_dropdown_users`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_users)